# Sql server mirroring: The remote copy of database is not related to the local copy of the database

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

I am trying to mirror a database following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31325/Step-by-Step-SQL-Mirroring-the-ASPState-Database)

At step 4, after I click on Start Mirror button I got

```
Error Number: 1407
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1
The remote copy of database "TEST_M" is not related to the local copy of the database.
```

I have restored the principal database backup to the mirror database with NORECOVERY.

Not sure what went wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I redo the backup and restore process and it worked.